# How to decrypt simple binary code to alphabet

Tags: cipher

Part of an alphabet is given by the code:

[image: Cipher]

This code is used by Fred to send a message home to his mum. She receives the following signal which includes a parity check digit on each word.

```
000000110111101011111111010010101110000011010
```

I have to find the message? I have tried solving directly but runs out of combinations. I need some hint or is there is some standard way to solve this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that every fifth digit is for parity check, your initial knowledge is:

```
00000 01101 11101 01111 11110 10010 10111 00000 11010
```

That is

```
0000(0) S
0110(1)
1110(1) N
0111(1) D
1111(0) [space]
1001(0) C
1011(1) A
0000(0) S
1101(0)
```

But you know that the two missing lettes are wrong. You can suppose that their parity check digit are correct, so the first sum should be odd and the latter even. Therefore, I'd say that the first letter should be corrected in `0010` (i.e. `E`) and the latter in `0101` (i.e. `H`), obtaining the message `SEND CASH`.